# how can I add an untracked file in my Github repo?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have an untracked `config.js` that stores a few development-mode variables in my local repo and a corresponding `config.js` on my VPS with the production-mode versions of the same variables. But I want to try out Github Pages. How do I add such an untracked `config.js` to my *Github* repository so that it doesn't get replicated when I do a `git pull` on my laptop? Or, if there is no way I can do this, is there any other way I can achieve this? That is, store some variables separately from the repo but use them for Github Pages website?

Comment: From my understanding, whatever files you add in GitHub will get added to git version control. Also since GitHub Pages only lets you use a static website, I don't know if you'd be able to get variables from somewhere using API calls or another method. Is there a reason as to why you don't want to have that file tracked in version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  There's a technical wording glitch here, but "you can't" is the short answer.  See below for details.

> Is there any other way I can achieve this?  That is, store some variables separately from the repo but use them for Github Pages website?

There are several options; I have no idea which ones might be good on GitHub Pages specifically.  This is, in fact, a Frequently Asked Question from the Git FAQ, where it's disguised as ["How to I tell Git to ignore tracked files?"](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F):

> A common reason to ask this question are configuration files which are added to a project as an example or default, but which individual developers may want to change. Keeping uncommitted changes around is undesirable in the long run, because git diff will always show the changes and they will be added for commit if commands such as `commit -a` or `add -u` are used.
>
> This problem can be solved in different ways:
>
> - Option a: Rename the configuration file to config.template or something like that, and tell the user to use it as a template. The install script for your system could also copy the template configuration to the appropriate location.
> - Option b: Allow configuration options to be overwritten in a seprate file. For example, in Makefiles it is common to add a line `-include config.mak`, which allows users to add custom configuration in `config.mak`, rather than changing the Makefile itself.
> - Option c: Make Git ignore changes to the configuration file. There is no automatic centralized way to do that. But on a per-clone basis you can tell Git to do it using either `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` or *sparse checkout* (see the corresponding section in [git-read-tree(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html) for details). Note that neither feature was designed for that purpose. *Use at own risk.*

I generally prefer the "template" option (option A).  Your software can typically do something like:

```
if exists("real-config-file"):
    load("real-config-file")
else:
    print("notice: using template config as fallback")
    load("template-config-file")
```

and now you get a working system even if you haven't configured it, but once you do configure it, you get a working system with *your configuration*.  The "install script" trick can also copy the template into place *as* the default initial configuration, provided there's an install phase in whatever system you're using.

#### The gory details

The phrase *tracked file*, in Git, refers specifically to *any file currently in the index*.  "The index" is a thing that Git calls by three different names: *index*, *staging area*, or *cache*.  I'm using "index" here because of the `git update-index` command and because the word "index" is relatively meaningless (which means it doesn't drag in too many false assumptions).

The index isn't actually part of any commit, and a repository is primarily a collection of commits.  So whether some file exists in some commit or not isn't the right question to ask—at least, not *yet*.  The right question is: *How, when, and why do files wind up in the index?*

The answer to *why* is the easiest.  A file goes into the index because you would like that file to be in your *next* commit.

The answer to *when* and *how* are trickier, because `git add` and `git rm` let you *manipulate the index one file at a time*, and other Git commands manipulate the index en-masse.  The big important ones are perhaps these:

- The act of *checking out* a commit, with `git checkout` or `git switch`, *fills in* the index (and your working tree) from a commit.
- The `git reset` command (in its "entire commit" mode) can reset the index to match a particular commit.  It will do so unless you use `--soft`.
- The `git merge` command uses the index to achieve the merge; the merge result is in the index (and your working tree).

So, if some file is in some particular commit, *checking out* that commit, or merging with it, will cause that file to wind up in the index.  As such, that file will be a *tracked file*.

But just because some file (`index.js` or whatever) is in commit `a123456` doesn't mean that that file is in commit `b789abc`.  If you switch to commit `b789abc` and that commit *lacks* `index.js`, the file will be *removed from* the index, if it's there now (provided that the `git switch` or `git checkout` succeeds).

The thing is, if it's removed from Git's index, it's also removed from your working tree.  **That is the effect you wish to avoid.**  So you must therefore avoid switching away from a commit where the file does exist, and therefore has been put into your index, to a commit where the file does not exist, and therefore is removed from your index and your working tree.  Well, **except when you want to observe the resulting behavior**, which is in fact every time you're using that commit!

So Git is (sort of) doing what you want.  It's what you want to want that's not reasonable.  More seriously, there definitely is something problematic here, but it's *really really hard to pin down how something should behave* other than to fall back to those three options in the Git FAQ.

Comment: Can't a [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) do the job?

Comment: @Orace: no. The file is either in a commit, or not; it's either in the index (and tracked), or not. There's no halfway state. It is possible to use `git add`, `git rm`, and `git update-index` in some hooks but playing this game is tricky and a bit dangerous (in particular `git commit --only` and `git commit --include` create two or three separate index files, all of which you'll need to handle, and there is no good way to do this).

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, @torek. Very helpful to understand what I suspected was not possible anyway.